# Element works, but not on wordpress site

Tags: plugins, jquery, css, javascript, html

I made an instagram widget on codepen.  It works great and it functions.  However, when I try adding it to my site it does not show up.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could get this instagram widget to work?

codepen - https://codepen.io/elle343/pen/owBoyE

my html

```html
<ul id="rudr_instafeed"></ul>
```

my css

```html
#rudr_instafeed{
   margin: 42px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center; 
  list-style:none;
}
#rudr_instafeed li{
display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
#rudr_instafeed li img{
max-height: 260px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
}
```

instagram-footer.js

```html
var token = '5219525.f0b48c7.17327f93adbe4fbb89ccd13a1a226a33',
    num_photos = 20;

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        for( x in data.data ){
            $('ul').append('<li><img src="'+data.data[x].images.low_resolution.url+'"></li>');
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

functions.php

```html
function instagramfooter() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'instagramfooter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/instagram-footer.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-2.2.4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.2.4', true );

}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'instagramfooter' );
```

In my JS folder
/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js (from here - https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js)

Comment: Do not add your own version of jQuery, use the built-in version you are already referring to in your enqueue- `array( 'jquery' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid conflict, WordPress requires you to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. So, in your code, you should replace `$.ajax()` with `jQuery.ajax()` and `$('ul')` with `jQuery('ul')`.

You can notice there are syntax errors in your browser's console, such as:

> Error: $.ajax is not defined

Comment: Thanks for the help, however there still seems to be a problem.  As soon as you load the page all of the image pop up scattered on the screen.  However, as I look in the background of all of these images the widget is showing up in the correct spot.

Comment: @user7548188 You're welcome. Can you please provide a screenshot, an error log, a link , etc. It's not easy to solve the issue just by knowing that `something is wrong`.

Comment: My site is on a local host.  I checked the error log, and it doesen't list any errors.  I've added a screenshot of what my screen looks like.  As you can see there are images scattered everywhere that are fixed to the page, but in the background you can see the widget is working